# SSH'd into a computer, uptime / who / users report 0 users?

Tags: ssh, users

I'm ssh'd into a server. Why doesn't the server report it?

```
# uptime
21:54:28 up 13 days,  3:47,  0 users,  load average: 1.18, 1.11, 1.13
# users
# who
```

I'm not really sure I understand it correctly, but shouldn't they list 1 user, since I'm obviously logged in (as root)?

Why it doesn't acknowledge me?

Comment: Is the file `/etc/utmp` missing?

Comment: Oh, actually it is missing. How to fix it?

Comment: Oops, the actual location is `/var/run/utmp` on Linux.

Comment: Ok, that file exists, and reads as "[xpts/1/1oot:pts/0:S.06�vQ".

Comment: It's a binary file, you can't read it with `cat`.

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much. But it almost says "root". Any idea what's wrong then?

Comment: What are the permissions on the file. Make sure it's world-readable.

Comment: Never mind. Since you're root, you would be able to read it regardless.

Comment: It was "-rw-rw-r--", now it's "-rwxrwxrwx". No change.

Comment: It should NOT be world-writable. And it doesn't need to be executable by anyone.

Comment: ok, now 644 again. So, any more ideas?

Comment: Note that it doesn't say `root`, it say `oot`. There's probably a null byte at the beginning of the name, which is how utmp entries are deleted when the user logs out.

Comment: @Barmar note there is no such thing as a distinction between binary and text files on Unix. All files use 8bit bytes/characters. Some files contain non ascii/utf-8 text, but ascii and utf-8 and everything else is binary.

Comment: I know that. The distinction I was making is whether the output of `cat filename` will be meaningful to a human reader.

Comment: Last time I saw something like this my machine was about to kick the bucket...not going to suggest it as a solution or anything, but if you aren't making backups, now might be a very good time.

Comment: Don't think that's the problem, it's a synology with some crazy RAID, so that shouldn't happen. It's controlling a whole factory hall, btw.. it'd better not die now xD No seriously, this thing happened for months. I'm just curious about the cause.

Comment: sometimes `sshd` will print useful errors to `/var/log/secure` on RHEL. You might check that to see if it says anything about utmp.

Comment: you should check your filesystem and perform maybe fsck to se if there are some fs issues, if i remeber well i had the same situation due filesystem incosistence

Comment: If you have `strace` installed, you could try running `strace uptime` and examining the output for any obvious issues. It should at least show you what files it is attempting to open.

Answer (score 0):

That can be caused by your PAM setup.

in sshd_config set that values and restart the sshd (be cautious, after that,  check that new ssh connection works before to close your current session)

```
UseLogin Yes    
UsePam No
```

If that fixes the problem, that is **not** the solution,  reverts to the initial conf and solves the PAM problem.